# Android studio start Failed Internal error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i've just download android studio but failed to start and get this error

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:296)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:243)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$1(MainRunner.java:41)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(java.awt.AWTEvent) accessible: module java.desktop does not "opens java.awt" to unnamed module @76bb7203
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtil.java:253)
    at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:270)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.EdtInvocationManager.<clinit>(EdtInvocationManager.java:33)
    ... 4 more

-----
Your JRE: 16.0.1+9-Ubuntu-1 aarch64 (Private Build)
/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-arm64
```

searched but not found anything